# Error about not finding bands

Tags: google-earth-engine

I run this code, but these errors occur:

> Image (Error)
> reduce.median: Error in map(ID=LE07_162034_20190303):
> Image.select: Pattern 'B1' did not match any bands.

> Confusion matrix:
> ConfusionMatrix (Error)
> reduce.median: Error in map(ID=LE07_162034_20190303):
> Image.select: Pattern 'B6' did not match any bands.

> FeatureCollection (Error)
> reduce.median: Error in map(ID=LE07_162034_20190303):
> Image.select: Pattern 'B1' did not match any bands.

```js
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);

var lc7 = landsat
.filterBounds(table)
.filterDate('2019-01-01','2020-01-01')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',10))
.map(function(img){
  var ms = img.select('B1', 'B2','B3','B4','B5').multiply(0.0001).clip(table);
  var tir = img.select('B6').multiply(0.1).clip(table);
  var ndvi = ms.normalizedDifference(['B3','B4']).rename('ndvi');
  var ndwi = ms.normalizedDifference(['B1','B7']).rename('ndwi');
  return ms.addBands(tir).addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndwi)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
})
.median();


var modis = modis_lulc
.filterDate('2019-01-01','2020-01-01')
.filterBounds(table)
.select('LC_Type2')
.toBands()
.clip(table);



Map.addLayer(lc7,[],'landsat_composite',false);


var vis = {min: 0, max:15, palette:['1c0dff', '05450a', '086a10', '54a708', '78d203',
  '009900','c6b044','dcd159','dade48','fbff13','b6ff05','27ff87',
  'c24f44', 'a5a5a5', 'ff6d4c','f9ffa4']};

Map.addLayer(modis,vis,'modis_lulc',false);




var cross = ee.Image.cat([lc7,modis]);

print(cross)


var training = cross.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 300,
  classBand: '2019_01_01_LC_Type2',
  region: table,
  scale: 30
});





var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(80)
    .train({
      features: training,
      classProperty: '2019_01_01_LC_Type2',
      inputProperties: ['B1', 'B2','B3','B4','B5','B7','ndvi', 'ndwi']
    });



var classified = lc7.classify(classifier);

Map.addLayer(classified,vis,'landsat_lulc',false);


var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();
print('Confusion matrix: ', trainAccuracy);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Training kappa coefficient: ', trainAccuracy.kappa());


// new accuracy assessment

var training = cross.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 100,
  classBand: '2019_01_01_LC_Type2',
  region: table,
  scale: 30,
  seed: 1
});

var validated = training.classify(classifier);

print(validated)


var testAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix('2019_01_01_LC_Type2', 'classification');
print('Validation error matrix: ', testAccuracy);
print('Validation overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Validation kappa coefficient: ', testAccuracy.kappa());

Export.image.toDrive({image:classified,description:'landCover2020',scale:30,region:table})
```

this is the link of my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/60a74690f9d38470ea92dfe29c86df37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Landsat 7 *Surface Reflectance* product. They have Band names with prefix 'SR_'. The bands need to be rescaled and the scaling factor is not 0.0001 as you have used.

```
        function applyScaleFactors(image) {
          var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
          var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
          return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
                      .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
        }
        
       var l7= landsat.map(applyScaleFactors);
var lc7 = l7
.filterBounds(table)
.filterDate('2019-01-01','2020-01-01')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',10))
.map(function(img){
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3','SR_B4']).rename('ndvi');
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B1','SR_B7']).rename('ndwi');
  return img.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndwi)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
})
.median()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will run it again.

Comment: I am beginner. you mean that I have to add the function you said before the median function I have wrote? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes. Use any kind of function after applying the scaling factor and usethe band names as SR_B1, SR_B2 etc. Kindly accept this as answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: unfortunately, it did not work. I rewrite my code based on your answer in another question. please the second question to check if I write correct or not.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/42cc461eb1b5ba140a931c52180680f1

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fhirsa%2FAliabad1%3ALandcover-Modis-Landsat8-2010

Comment: I have sent the link of my codes. would you open it please Padmanabha?

Comment: I have edited my answer.